# fs2 Task.start vs async

Tags: task, scalaz, fs2

I have two tasks:

```
  val t = System.currentTimeMillis()

  def first: fs2.Task[Int] = fs2.Task.fromFuture(Future.successful {
    println(s"${ System.currentTimeMillis() - t} - First")
    Thread.sleep(100)
    1
  })

  def second: fs2.Task[Int] = fs2.Task.fromFuture(Future.successful {
    println(s"${System.currentTimeMillis() - t} - Second")
    Thread.sleep(200)
    2
  })
```

I want to start them in parallel, and run a function on results in the end (pretty much as I'd do vs Applicative map2).
This works perfectly fine:

```
  val comb = for {
    ta ← fs2.Task.start(first)
    tb ← fs2.Task.start(second)
    a ← ta
    b ← tb
  } yield {
    println("Complete")
    a + b
  }

comb.unsafeRun()
```

output: **164 - First
164 - Second**

It is a bit tedious to write extra line in for comprehension every time.
To my suprise neither

```
import fs2.interop.scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._
val comb2 = (first |@| second) {_ + _}
```

output: **197 - First 318 - Second**

nor

```
  val comb1 = for {
    a ← first.async
    b ← second.async
  } yield {
    a + b
  }
```

output: **202 - First 323 - Second**

worked.
While in the first case tasks started simultaneuosly, in the latter 2, they began one after another.

What am I missing? 
Reading the implementation of `async` I understood, that intent is to make first snippet syntactically attractive, but I cant believe that there is a bug, so I possibly just misuse async?

Comment: The `fs2.Task` class was removed, in favour of `cats.effect.Task`. Thus, the question as formulated is not relevant. 

It would be interesting to check if the effect also appears with `cats.effect.IO`, `monix.Task`, or `scalaz.Zio`.